# Creating multiple XML files from one vanilla XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have several different XSLT files that all work on the same original XML file to produce four different XML file outputs. Is it possible to make all these XSLT files into one using vanilla XSLT (that is, not using XALAN or anything that's XSLT-parser specific)?

All help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: Can be done, but requires quite a big effort. If you modify your question to ask just how this can be done, I will provide the answer. Requiring to write the actual transformation is asking too-much, I can do this for a bounty :).

Comment: There's other people more charitable than you on this subject. Also, you have more rep than you can know what to do with. Would -1 if it were possible on comments. Your attitude is contrary to the attitude of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to produce multiple files from a single XSLT, in an XSLT 2.0 styelsheet.

In XSLT 2.0 [**xsl:result-document**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document) can be used multiple times to produce multiple output files.

Depending on how the individual XSLT stylesheets are written, you may be able to **import** or **include** the stylesheets into a "parent" stylesheet that uses **[xsl:result-document](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document)** to execute different **named templates** or **apply-templates** with different **context** and/or **modes** to output the different files.

Comment: In Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, whenever I create an xsl:result-document element under an xsl:template element, I get the highlighting under the xsl:result-document saying that it's an invalid child. Does VS not accept XSLT v. 2.0?

Comment: I don't think so.  Microsoft has yet to build support for XSLT 2.0.  Saxon has a .NET implementation that can be used http://saxon.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I just started using xsl:result-document in a basic example in Saxon, I will try to implement it with my scripts and share my results.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You could to use [`<xsl:import>`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_import.asp)</strike>

**EDIT**

No, this code will not generate four XML files, but merge several XSLT files to be processed as one. You can't achieve that without interacting with your XSLT processor, as XSLT itself doesn't care about files, just to translate a XML format into another.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I use <xsl:import> to import the four files that I currently have? Would that even work?

Comment: I understood you have several XSLT files to merge, not XML files. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but the merged XSLT files must still produce 4 file outputs. Would this method do that?